# jedis MasterListener initPool many times

Tags: jedis

jedis src code MasterListener method run:

```
     j.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
          log.fine("Sentinel " + host + ":" + port + " published: " + message + ".");

          String[] switchMasterMsg = message.split(" ");

          if (switchMasterMsg.length > 3) {

            if (masterName.equals(switchMasterMsg[0])) {
              initPool(toHostAndPort(Arrays.asList(switchMasterMsg[3], switchMasterMsg[4])));
            } else {
              log.fine("Ignoring message on +switch-master for master name "
                  + switchMasterMsg[0] + ", our master name is " + masterName);
            }

          } else {
            log.severe("Invalid message received on Sentinel " + host + ":" + port
                + " on channel +switch-master: " + message);
          }
        }
      }, "+switch-master");
```

if there has three Sentinels,so created three MasterListener.When failover happens,jedis client will initPool three times for each MasterListener.

The question is：why not just initPool once? When sentinel objective offline master,then jedis client receive message to re-initPool?

Answer (score 0):

I think synchronization is needed at this line "if (!master.equals(currentHostMaster)) {" to prevent create connection pool multiple times.

```
    public class JedisSentinelPool extends JedisPoolAbstract {
    private volatile HostAndPort currentHostMaster;
    private void initPool(HostAndPort master) {
    if (!master.equals(currentHostMaster)) {
      currentHostMaster = master;
      if (factory == null) {

}
```